# login view does not load before main ViewController in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode

Here is the layout of my app.

1. ApplicationName

   - LoginViewController.h
   - LoginViewController.m
   - LoginView.xib
   - AppDelegate.h
   - AppDelegate.m
   - ViewController.h
   - ViewController.m
   - ViewController_iPhone.xib
   - ViewController_iPad.xib

Currently in my AppDelegate.m I have:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    LoginViewController *_loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    self.loginViewController = _loginViewController;
    [_loginViewController release];
    [_window addSubview:[loginViewController view]];                                                                                                                            

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPhone" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    } else {
        self.viewController = [[[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController_iPad" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    }
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

My LoginView.xib has it's File's Owner defined as LoginViewController.

I was at first getting an error stating: reason: '-[UITableViewController loadView] loaded the "LoginView" nib but didn't get a UITableView.'"

I changed UITableViewController to UIViewController and I was able to run the app without an error. The only problem now is that my LoginViewController does not load. I see the blank grey ViewController_iPad.xib loading.

What am I missing here?

I can post up any other code that would be useful.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be setting your window's root view controller to `self.loginViewController`.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    self.loginViewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
    [self.loginViewController release];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.loginViewController;                                                                                                                      
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're block of code you're talking about, but I think you don't need anything else.

Comment: LoginViewController *_loginViewController = [[LoginViewController     alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
        self.loginViewController = _loginViewController;
        [_loginViewController release];
        [_window addSubview:[loginViewController view]];

Comment: It does work how you told me though. Now just to get this to move to the ViewController view when a successful login is made.

Comment: I simplified your code in my version.  Also, your version tries to add a view to the window before it actually creates the window.